# parsing in c# to get a callersid

Tags: c#, twilio

I have this string

> "=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&**CallSid=CA35b8f8162eeffebf07d4fc7c9aeadd94**&To=%2B123475&CallerZip=406&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B12606&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=AUBURN&Caller=%2B1265506&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=AURN&CalledState=IN&FromZip=466&FromState=IN"

I would like to get the CallSid from this string. what would be the best way to achieving this?

Comment: Use String.Split (two times)

Comment: Please edit your question to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with help of quite simple Regular Expression.

There is very good article on that topic on [DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex).

```
var input = "=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA35b8f8162eeffebf07d4fc7c9aeadd94&To=%2B123475&CallerZip=406&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B12606&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=AUBURN&Caller=%2B1265506&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=AURN&CalledState=IN&FromZip=466&FromState=IN";

var regex = new Regex(@"\&CallSid=([a-z0-9]+)\&", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var match = regex.Match(input);
var result = match
    .Groups[1] // First round brackets has index "1"
    .Captures[0] // You expect to have only one match
    .Value;
```

**Regex options**

`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Means that regular expression is not case sensitive.

`RegexOptions.Compiled`

It could be useful to precompile the regular expression if you are going to use it more than few times. This can slightly improve the performance.

**Regex playground**

Check out the playground to understand how it works: https://regex101.com/r/pU6KMz/1

Comment: You have exactly such result in the example. Just try the C# code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1P4Z1x

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString function, you would need to use the System.Web assembly, but it won't require a web context.

```
    string querystring = "=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA35b8f8162eeffebf07d4fc7c9aeadd94&To=%2B123475&CallerZip=406&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B12606&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=AUBURN&Caller=%2B1265506&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=AURN&CalledState=IN&FromZip=466&FromState=IN";
    NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
    string callSID = qscoll["CallSid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-Regex method.

```
const string BEGIN_MARKER = "CallSid=";

var str = "=inbound&CallerState=IN&ToZip=&CallSid=CA35b8f8162eeffebf07d4fc7c9aeadd94&To=%2B123475&CallerZip=406&ToCountry=US&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CalledZip=&CalledCity=&CallStatus=ringing&From=%2B12606&AccountSid=ACc6d06b4cb61ccbfa61bf461957a5a626&CalledCountry=US&CallerCity=AUBURN&Caller=%2B1265506&FromCountry=US&ToCity=&FromCity=AURN&CalledState=IN&FromZip=466&FromState=IN";
var begin = str.IndexOf(BEGIN_MARKER) + BEGIN_MARKER.Length;
var end = str.IndexOf('&', begin);

var sid = str.Substring(begin, end - begin);
```

Using the `CallSid=` part, we retrieve the index of the first character of the `Sid`, then retrieve the end position of the `Sid` using that. When using `string.Substring(char value, int startIndex)`, the method starts to search beginning at the `startIndex`.

Finally, use both values to extract a substring.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that is to split the string on the `&` character, then find the part that starts with `"CallSid="`, and if that exists, split it on the `=` character and take the second item (at index `1`):

```
var callSid = input
    .Split('&')
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("CallSid=",
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    ?.Split('=')[1];  // '?.' is used here in case result is null
```